# How to substitue values from a 'staging' table for each row that meets the criteria?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say that I have a table (Table1) that has the following data.

```
VALUE_ID    VALUE      CODE    HOUR     TYPE
   1        null        DEF     1        REG
   2        null        DEF     2        REG
   3        null        DEF     3        REG
```

Let's say I have a Materialized View (MV1) (joins a couple different tables) that looks like this:

```
 VALUE_ID    VALUE      CODE    HOUR     TYPE     CALC_VALUE    DEFAULT_VALUE
    1        null       DEF      1        REG         8               2
    2        null       DEF      2        REG         12              1
    3        null       DEF      3        REG         25              0
```

I want to write a script that that updates **Table1** and sets the VALUE to either the value present in the **CALC_VALUE** column or **DEFAULT_VALUE** column from **MV1**. Below is my attempt:

```
 Update Table1
    SET value = (select calc_value from MV1)
  WHERE TYPE = 'REG' 
    AND HOUR = 2;
  COMMIT;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *sets the VALUE to either the value present in the CALC_VALUE column or DEFAULT_VALUE* based on what?

Comment: @forpas - so let's say that I have a entry in value that has a type of 'REG'. I want to substitute the value from the CALC_VALUE column in the MV1 Materialized View for ALL Values in the Table1 table that meet that criteria. (so any value that has type = 'REG');

Comment: And when will the column `DEFAULT_VALUE` be used for the update?

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't provide that because I figured if I could get the method for updating the first scenario, the second one would be a cakewalk since I could apply that same concept to it. The condition would be if Code <> 'DEF' and value is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Table1
    SET value = (select calc_value from MV1 where table1.value_id = mv1.value_id)
    WHERE TYPE = 'REG' AND HOUR = 2;
  COMMIT;
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I was looking for! Was my question bad one? not sure why I was receiving negative responses / ratings...